# How to sort records by relation field using relation fields column in Doctrine?

Tags: php, sorting, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have 2 entities in relation ManyToOne. ScheduledEvent and Tariff entites.

First entity is ScheduledEvent with field tariff where tariff is ManyToOne relation. And I have configured it like this in ScheduledEvent entity:

```
 /**
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Tariff", inversedBy="scheduledEvents")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="tariff_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 **/
private $tariff;
```

And Tariff entity that has 'name' and 'scheduledEvents' fields set up like this:

```
/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=255)
 */
private $name;


/**
*
* @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="ScheduledEvent", mappedBy="tariff")
*/
private $scheduledEvents;
```

Is it possible to configure ScheduledEvent entity in annotaion or some other way so that when I select records from ScheduledEvent entity I sort by Tariffs name column.

So for example when I build query like this:

```
$repository = $em->getRepository('SMAPIBundle:ScheduledEvent');
$repository->createQueryBuilder('sce')
       ->setFirstResult(0)
       ->setMaxResults(10)
       ->orderBy('sce.tariff', $sortColumnOrder);
```

I want to be able to tell him only to sort by tariff but configure it to sort by Tariff's name column instead of id when I sort ScheduledEvent records by tariff.

Is this possible?

I know where is OrderBy annotation:

```
/**
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Tariff", inversedBy="scheduledEvents")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="tariff_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 * @ORM\OrderBy("name")
 **/
private $tariff;
```

But that is only used for ManyToMany and OneToMany relations.

So any ideas on how to sort by relation field using **relation fields column** when retrieving records for entity?

I am using Doctrine 2.4.6.

Answer (score 2):

You can do that if you join `tariff` first:

```
$repository = $em->getRepository('SMAPIBundle:ScheduledEvent');
$repository->createQueryBuilder('sce')
       ->leftJoin('sce.tariff', 't')
       ->setFirstResult(0)
       ->setMaxResults(10)
       ->orderBy('t.name', $sortColumnOrder);
```

Comment: I can not do that because sort column name is dynamic and I do not know what column will be sorted.

Comment: `t.name` is a string. Make it a variable.

Comment: I cant join tables either because this logic is used for all entities.

Comment: Why don't you say what you want in your question, so it can be answered directly without this discussion.