# SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column in 'field list' while trying to sort entities

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I am trying to implement sorting in my Symfony 6 project.

Here is the entity I am trying to sort :

```php
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use App\Entity\Workflow\Status;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use App\Entity\Plant;
use App\Entity\DetailedCause;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=\App\Repository\RequestRepository::class)
 */
class Request
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;
    
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     */
    private $requesterName;
    
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     */
    private $requesterService;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     */
    private $requesterMatricule;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $priority;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $type;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="boolean")
     */
    private $flagSupp;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer", nullable=true)
     */
    private $estimatedLoad;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="text")
     */
    private $reason;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime", nullable=false)
     */
    private $date;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity=Workflow\Status::class)
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */
    private Status $state;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=50, nullable=true)
     */
    private $product;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=50, nullable=true)
     */
    private $program;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity=DetailedCause::class)
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */
    private DetailedCause $detailedCause;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity=Cause::class)
     */ 
    private $cause;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity=Plant::class)
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */
    private Plant $impactedPlant;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity=Action::class, mappedBy="request")
     */
    private $actions;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity=Plant::class)
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */
    private Plant $requesterPlant;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->actions = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getRequesterPlant(): ?Plant
    {
        return $this->requesterPlant;
    }

    public function setRequesterPlant(?Plant $requesterPlant): self
    {
        $this->requesterPlant = $requesterPlant;

        return $this;
    }

    //the rest of getters and setters

    
}
```

and the repository :

```php
<?php

namespace App\Repository;

use App\Entity\Request;
use App\Entity\RequestFilter;
use Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\Repository\ServiceEntityRepository;
use Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Pagination\Paginator;
use Doctrine\Persistence\ManagerRegistry;
use App\Entity\Plant;

/**
 * @method Request|null find($id, $lockMode = null, $lockVersion = null)
 * @method Request|null findOneBy(array $criteria, array $orderBy = null)
 * @method Request[]    findAll()
 * @method Request[]    findBy(array $criteria, array $orderBy = null, $limit = null, $offset = null)
 * @method Paginator    getRequestPaginator(int $offset = 0, string $order = 'id')
 */
class RequestRepository extends ServiceEntityRepository
{
    public function __construct(ManagerRegistry $registry)
    {
        parent::__construct($registry, Request::class);
    }

    /**
     * @var int $offset
     * @param RequestFilter
     * @return Paginator Returns a paginator of requests using filters
     */
    public function getRequestPaginator($offset = 0, RequestFilter $filter = null)
    {
        if ($filter == null) {
            $filter = new RequestFilter();
        }

        #adds filter parameters to the query
        $query = $this->createQueryBuilder('r');
        if ($filter->getStates() != null){
            $query
                ->andWhere('r.state IN (:states)')
                ->setParameter('states', $filter->getStates());//;
        }
        #adds the rest of the params
        $query = $query
            //this orderBy clause is triggering the error
            ->orderBy('r.' . $filter->getOrder(), $filter->getOrderDirection())
            ->setFirstResult($offset)
            ->setMaxResults($filter->getRequestsPerPage())
            ->getQuery();
        return new Paginator($query);
    }
}
```

this works fine for most attributes. I can sort by date, requester name, etc.

But when I try to sort by requesterPlant, which is a doctrine Entity, I get the following error :

("An exception occurred while executing a query: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'r0_.requester_plant_id' in 'field list'").

This column *does* exist in the database just like other columns. I do not understand why doctrine is stuck on this. Migrations are up to date, I've cleared cache, and I've been stuck on this problem for days.

I would really appreciate if anyone had a clue about what is happening there.

As additional info, here is my Plant entity :

```php
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=\App\Repository\PlantRepository::class)
 */
class Plant
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Request", mappedBy="requesterPlant")
     */
    private int $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private string $designation;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=50)
     */
    private string $plantString;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=50)
     */
    private string $company;


    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function setID(int $id): self
    {
        $this->id = $id;
        return $this;
    }

    public function getDesignation(): ?string
    {
        return $this->designation;
    }

    public function setDesignation(string $designation): self
    {
        $this->designation = $designation;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getPlantString(): ?string
    {
        return $this->plantString;
    }

    public function setPLantString(string $plantString): self
    {
        $this->plantString = $plantString;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getCompany(): ?string
    {
        return $this->company;
    }

    public function setCompany(string $company): self
    {
        $this->company = $company;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

Comment: You may need to join relation to use in sorting. and update line to `$query->join('r. requesterPlant', 'rp')->orderBy('rp.id', $filter->getOrderDirection())`; https://stackoverflow.com/a/26789634/4896948

Comment: What is the value of  $filter->getOrder()? requesterPlant? or requesterPlantId?

Comment: @NuryagdyMustapayev thank you, this works! This is one step toward my ideal solution. However, I have to sort by standard fields too (strings, ints...), and this raises an exception as these fields do not have an associated entity. Is it possible to know at runtime which field of an entity is an association ? That way I could use two separate queries.

Comment: Simple solution is to use if condition and check which entity's property `$filter->getOrder()`'s value is, and set orderBy accordingly

Comment: @NuryagdyMustapayev Right... I was facing a problem because getOrder() returns strings, but I realize now that I just need to modify it so it can pass the entity itself. Thank you !

Comment: @Monnomcjo the value of getOrder() is a string corresponding to the name of the `Request` attribute to sort by. I realize now it was a bad idea to "stringify" the attributes. I figured doctrine could sort using the IDs, but I see now it isn't how this works.

Comment: I was just saying, what if getOrder returns requester_plant and not requester_plant_id?